# Smooth color change animation of patch in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import animation

matplotlib.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(10, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()



ax.axis("equal")
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)



def animate(i):
    circle1 = Circle((0.1, 0.1), 0.2, color = '#' + str(i)*6)
    circle2 = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color = '#ffff00')        
    ax.add_artist(circle1);
    ax.add_artist(circle2);

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=9, interval=1000, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Inside my animate function, i am trying a smooth transition from black to grey for my first circle patch. However, it doesn't work. Can someone please help? Also, I need a smooth border animation too. Is it possible to have seperate face color and border color animations for same patch? If yes, then how ?

Comment: You add two new circles in each frame. After 9 frames you have 18 circles in your plot. You won't see them if using `blit`, but that would require to return the circles from your `animate` function: `return circle1, circle2`.